# Generate Rails models with mandatory/required fields (i.e not null) from command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone please help with generating Rails models with mandatory fields/columns (i.e. NOT NULL)? For example,

```
$rails generate model Role name:string <???>
```

What do I need to specify in order to get the "null: false" constraint as shown below?

```
class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      **t.string :name, null: false**

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks heaps in advance

Comment: Just write the :null => false in your generated migration and then migrate it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can't do that in a generator command. It's quite simple to add `null: false` to your migration file though.

Comment: What a shame :). I was hoping to keep it consistent by generating models from the command line so that I don't have to touch the files and avoid do something on the command line and something in the migration file. Cheers for that!

Comment: I feel your pain man. But keep in mind, the best way to learn is to get your hands dirty in the code. Feel free to vote up my answer though, and if you need any help with the migrations I'd be happy to do so.

Comment: To drive a nail in this coffin, I'd like to add that [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers) explicitly say "`null` and `default` cannot be specified via command line".

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to change an existing column to `null: false` like I did:

```rb
class MakeRoleNameNotNull < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column_null :roles, :name, false
  end
end
```